# Vue data from app.js is not showing in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My console is [image]

and my `app.js` is like this

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'my new msg'
  }
});
```

and my blade template is like this

```
<div id="app">
  @{{ msg }}
</div>
```

Comment: In your home.blade.php are you including a link to the js file?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not having the component placed inside the blade file.

Add the `<example-component></example-component>` tag into your `home.blade.php` or whichever `.blade.php` file that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The code to put in your **home.blade.php**

```
  <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>

  </body>
```